# on select drop down change hide/show checkboxes depending on option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have  a series of buttons which i use to turn off/on all check boxes for each day of the week which at the moment looks really messy so i would like to turn all the buttons into a drop down select field which on changing the option to Monday for example would run the Monday jquery to hide all of the Monday check boxes.

here is the html

```
<input type='submit' name='submit_performances' value='update all'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle' name='select-all-toggle' value='Hide/Show all Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-monday' name='select-all-toggle-monday' value='Hide/Show all Monday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-tuesday' name='select-all-toggle-tuesday' value='Hide/Show all Tuesday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-wednesday' name='select-all-toggle-wednesday' value='Hide/Show all Wednesday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-thursday' name='select-all-toggle-thursday' value='Hide/Show all Thursday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-friday' name='select-all-toggle-friday' value='Hide/Show all Friday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-saturday' name='select-all-toggle-saturday' value='Hide/Show all Saturday Performances'>
    <input type='button' id='select-all-toggle-sunday' name='select-all-toggle-sunday' value='Hide/Show all Sunday Performances'>
    </form>
```

here is the jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.select-all-identifier').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.select-all-identifier').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-monday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.monday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.monday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-tuesday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.tuesday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.tuesday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-wednesday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.wednesday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.wednesday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-thursday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.thursday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.thursday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-friday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.friday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.friday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-saturday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.saturday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.saturday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all-toggle-sunday').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.sunday').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.sunday').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You dont need to declare the document.ready each time you have a new toggle. Just once is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Checking documentation ftw! the jquery docs have an event that handles exactly this, here's the page:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

If you scroll down a little, you'll see that there's an interactive example showing how it works with a select box, which if I'm not mistaken is exactly what you are after.

Also, a couple general javascript tips based on your example code:

1. As someone mentioned in the comment above, you only need one document ready, and you can put all your code inside of that single function.
2. Don't repeat yourself! you can turn all those separate methods into one method by parsing the selector string. If you put two classes on each button rather than one ID, you can effectively cut most of the code here. The first class would be `select-all-toggle` and the second class would be the day of the week. Then you can run the toggle and change events on any element with the `.select-all-toggle` selector, and use jquery's `$(el).attr('class')` to pull off the second class and get back the value of the day.

I could definitely write a cleaner answer here for you, but I don't think that's conducive to learning. Read over the suggestions here and try revising your code -- I bet you can make this work without me just feeding you an answer : )